# Software floating-point multiplication

Tags: c++, floating-point

I wrote a floating-point multiplication function as an excercise. The program compares its result to the usual hardware multiplication result and for this purpose I use unspecified behavior, but the function itself should be fine. I do get warnings about XOR-ing 1-bit ints but I have no idea why.

I noticed there aren't that many comments in the multiplication function so I wonder what I could put there.

```cpp
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <float.h>

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int msb( uint64_t v )
{
    if(v == 0) return 0;
    return 63-__builtin_clzll(v);
}

void roundedShift(uint64_t* a, unsigned int n) {    
    if(n >= sizeof(uint64_t)*CHAR_BIT) {
        // we don't care about rounding if n == 64 because mantissa product is always less than 2^46
        *a = 0;
    }
    uint64_t roundoff = *a - ((*a >> n) << n);
    *a >>= n;
    if(roundoff*2 > (1ull<<n)
            ||
       (roundoff*2 == (1ull<<n) && (*a)%2 == 1)) {
        ++(*a);
    }
}

struct SoftFloat {
    unsigned int mantissa : 23; 
    unsigned int exponent : 8;
    unsigned int sign : 1;

    static const SoftFloat nan;
    SoftFloat operator *(SoftFloat right) const {
        if(exponent == 255 || right.exponent == 255) {
            return specialMultiplication(right);
        }
        uint64_t fullLeftMantissa = (mantissa)+(exponent!=0?(1<<23):0);
        uint64_t fullRightMantissa = (right.mantissa)+(right.exponent!=0?(1<<23):0);
        uint64_t fullNewMantissa = fullLeftMantissa * fullRightMantissa;
        // experiment have shown that operating on biased exponents is faster than 
            // computing unbiased exponent and then adding bias
        short leftNormalBiasedExponent = exponent != 0 ? exponent: 1; 
        short rightNormalBiasedExponent = right.exponent != 0 ? right.exponent : 1;
        short newNormalBiasedExponent = leftNormalBiasedExponent + 
                                        rightNormalBiasedExponent - 127 - 23;

        int totalShift = 0;
        if(newNormalBiasedExponent < 1) {
            int diff = -newNormalBiasedExponent + 1;
            newNormalBiasedExponent = 1;
            totalShift += diff;
        }
        int implicitBit = msb(fullNewMantissa);
        int shift = implicitBit - totalShift - 23;
        if(shift >= 0) {
            newNormalBiasedExponent += shift;
            totalShift += shift;
            fullNewMantissa &= ~(1ll << implicitBit);
        } else {
            newNormalBiasedExponent = 0;
        }
        roundedShift(&fullNewMantissa, totalShift);
        if(fullNewMantissa == (1 << 23)) {
            ++newNormalBiasedExponent;
            fullNewMantissa = 0;
        }
        if(newNormalBiasedExponent >= 255) {
            newNormalBiasedExponent = 255;
            fullNewMantissa = 0;
        }
        return SoftFloat{(uint)fullNewMantissa, (uint)newNormalBiasedExponent, sign ^ right.sign};
        // i don't really understan why this return expression gives warning
        // narrowing conversion of ‘(((int)((const SoftFloat*)this)->SoftFloat::sign) ^ ((int)right.SoftFloat::sign))’ from ‘int’ to ‘unsigned int’
    }
    bool isNan() const {
        return exponent == 255 && mantissa != 0;
        // This is same as (*reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int*>(this) << 1) > 0b11111111000000000000000000000000u, 
        // but the experiments have shown it doesn't make any difference for speed on my machine.
        // Current version does not invoke any UB 
    }
    bool isZero() const {
        return exponent == 0 && mantissa == 0;
    }

    bool isRepresentationEqual(const SoftFloat& right) {
        return !memcmp(this, &right, sizeof(SoftFloat));
    }

    // Correctness testing relies on specific layout of floats and of fields inside SoftFloat, but the multiplication function itself does not
    float toHardFloat() const {
        float res;
        memcpy(&res, this, sizeof(SoftFloat));
        return res;
    }
    static SoftFloat fromOrdinalNumber(const unsigned int& a) {
        SoftFloat res;
        memcpy(&res, &a, sizeof(SoftFloat));
        return res;
    }
    static SoftFloat fromHardFloat(const float& a) {
        SoftFloat res;
        memcpy(&res, &a, sizeof(SoftFloat));
        return res;
    }
private:
    SoftFloat specialMultiplication(SoftFloat right) const {
        // precondition - at least one of *this, right is either inf, -inf or nan
        if(isNan() || right.isNan()) {
            return nan;
        }
        if(isZero() || right.isZero()) {
            return nan;
        }
        return {0, 255, sign ^ right.sign};
    }
};
const SoftFloat SoftFloat::nan = {1, 255, 0};

std::mutex coutMutex;
void checkOneMultiplication(SoftFloat left, SoftFloat right) {
    SoftFloat softProduct = left*right;
    SoftFloat hardProduct = SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(
                                       left.toHardFloat() *
                                       right.toHardFloat());
    bool equalRepresentation = softProduct.isRepresentationEqual(hardProduct);
    bool bothNan = softProduct.isNan() && 
                   hardProduct.isNan();
    if(!(equalRepresentation || bothNan)) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(coutMutex);
        std::cerr << "failed\n";
        std::cerr << "left operand\t" << left.mantissa << "  " << left.exponent << "  " << left.sign << "  " << left.toHardFloat() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "right operand\t" << right.mantissa << "  " << right.exponent << "  " << right.sign << "  " << right.toHardFloat() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "soft product\t" << softProduct.mantissa << "  " << softProduct.exponent << "  " << softProduct.sign << "  " << softProduct.toHardFloat() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "hard product\t" << hardProduct.mantissa << "  " << hardProduct.exponent << "  " << hardProduct.sign << "  " << hardProduct.toHardFloat() << std::endl;
        abort();
    }
}

void checkRange(unsigned int start, unsigned int end, int threadNumber) {
    // this loop checks multiplication with every one of 2^28 possible floats in given range of representaions. Right operand is pseudorandom but deterministic
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> distr;
    std::mt19937 gen(threadNumber);
    for(unsigned int representationNumber = start; representationNumber != end; representationNumber++) {
        // can't use < in condition because last block ends with 0
        int rigntOperandRepresentationNumber = distr(gen);
        SoftFloat leftOperand = SoftFloat::fromOrdinalNumber(representationNumber);
        SoftFloat rightOperand = SoftFloat::fromOrdinalNumber(rigntOperandRepresentationNumber);
        checkOneMultiplication(leftOperand, rightOperand);
        if(representationNumber%0x10000000 == 0 && representationNumber > start) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(coutMutex);
            std::cout << "thread " << threadNumber << " checked 0x" << std::hex << representationNumber-start << " multiplications" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static_assert(sizeof(SoftFloat) == sizeof(float));
    static_assert(alignof(SoftFloat) == alignof(float), "");
    static_assert(sizeof(SoftFloat) == sizeof(int), "");
    static_assert(__BYTE_ORDER__ == LITTLE_ENDIAN, "");
    // Unfortunately we can't statically check further details of layout of structures

    assert(SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(std::numeric_limits<float>::denorm_min()).isRepresentationEqual(SoftFloat{1, 0, 0}));
    assert(SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(FLT_MIN).isRepresentationEqual(SoftFloat{0, 1, 0}));

    float nonConstant = -1;
    assert(SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(nonConstant*0).isRepresentationEqual(SoftFloat{0, 0, 1}));
    // Test can't run if any of the above asserts fail


    const int threadCount = 4;
    fesetround(FE_TONEAREST); // assuming mantissa is rounded to even when there are two nearest

    std::thread threads[threadCount-1];

    const unsigned int blockSize = UINT32_MAX/4+1;

    for(int i = 1; i < threadCount; i++) {
        threads[i-1] = std::thread(checkRange, blockSize*i, blockSize*(i+1), i);
    }
    checkRange(0, blockSize, 0);

    SoftFloat specialCases[] = {{0, 0, 0}, // 0
                                {0, 0, 1}, // -0
                                {0, 255, 0}, //inf
                                {0, 255, 1}, //-inf
                                SoftFloat::nan,
                                SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(std::nanf("")),
                                SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(FLT_MIN),
                                SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(1),
                                SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(FLT_MAX),
                                SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(FLT_EPSILON),
                                SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(std::numeric_limits<float>::denorm_min()),
                                SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(-FLT_MAX),
                                SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(FLT_MIN_EXP),
                                SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(FLT_MIN_10_EXP),
                                SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(FLT_MAX_EXP),
                                SoftFloat::fromHardFloat(FLT_MAX_10_EXP)};
    int numberOfSpecialCases = sizeof(specialCases)/sizeof(SoftFloat);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSpecialCases; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numberOfSpecialCases; j++) {
            checkOneMultiplication(specialCases[i], specialCases[j]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < threadCount; i++) {
        threads[i-1].join();
    }

    std::cout << "checked 0x" << UINT32_MAX + numberOfSpecialCases*numberOfSpecialCases << " multiplications";
    return 0;
}
```

The program tests multiplication of every possible floating-point number with a random number. This takes a long time to run, so I made it threaded. I also used fancy C++11 RNG stuff to make it deterministic.

The function uses `__builtin_clzll` which is available on gcc and clang but not on MSVC, I believe.

Comment: What (compiler, OS, standard) are you targeting?

Comment: Let's say gcc, linux, x64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fairly good code overall.

Mostly small stuff below.

**Narrowing**

> I do get warnings about XOR-ing 1-bit ints but I have no idea why.

Weak compiler.

Perhaps use `bool sign : 1;`

**Naked magic numbers**

Rather than 23, 127, etc, consider the C-ish

```
#define MANTISSA_BIT_WIDTH 23
```

or a C++ -ish

```
const int mantissa_bit_width = 23;
```

**`uint`?**

`uint` appears non-standard.  Perhaps `unsigned`?

```
// return SoftFloat{(uint)fullNewMantissa, (uint)newNormalBiasedExponent, sign ^ right.sign};
return SoftFloat{(unsigned)fullNewMantissa, (unsigned)newNormalBiasedExponent, sign ^ right.sign};
```

---

Minor stuff

**Portability**

Although OP has "gcc, linux, x64", little changes would step toward portability without sacrificing efficient emitted code.

```
// if(fullNewMantissa == (1 << 23)) {
if(fullNewMantissa == (1ul << 23)) {  // `int` could be 16-bit

// fullNewMantissa &= ~(1ll << implicitBit);
fullNewMantissa &= ~(1ull << implicitBit);  // Why mess with signed shifts?
```

**`int` vs. `short`**

Rarely is `short` faster/better than `int` unless one has an array of the type.

Consider

```
// short leftNormalBiasedExponent, rightNormalBiasedExponent, newNormalBiasedExponent
int leftNormalBiasedExponent, rightNormalBiasedExponent, newNormalBiasedExponent
```

**sizeof type vs sizeof object**

Consider the clearer, less maintenance

```
// return !memcmp(this, &right, sizeof(SoftFloat));
return !memcmp(this, &right, sizeof *this);
```

**`roundedShift()`**

Unclear about `roundedShift()` correctness.  Partly due to lack of comments, partly due to "it takes time" to analyze.

Comment: I doubt *weak compiler* - the 1-bit `unsigned` are each promoted to `int` for the XOR, so narrowing to 1-bit `unsigned` warrants a warning.  Changing the type to `bool` and using `!=` in place of `^` is a good suggestion, though.

Answer (score 3):

Using the C compatibility headers is questionable in new code:

> ```
> #include <math.h>
> #include <assert.h>
> #include <memory.h>
> #include <limits.h>
> #include <fenv.h>
> #include <float.h>
> ```

I recommend using the C++ versions (`<cmath>` etc.) which define their identifiers in the `std` namespace.

We're missing an include of `<stdint.h>` for `uint64_t` (or better, include `<cstdint>` to define `std::uint64_t`).  Do we really need a 64-bit type, or would `std::fast_uint64_t` be a better choice?

There are many instances of `sizeof` with a typename argument, which would be clearer with an ordinary expression argument.  For example:

> ```
>     SoftFloat res;
>     memcpy(&res, &a, sizeof(SoftFloat));
>     return res;
> ```

Here we can show that we're correctly passing the size of the destination argument:

```
    SoftFloat res;
    std::memcpy(&res, &a, sizeof res);
    return res;
```